# localhost cannot be accessed-using xampp

Tags: mysql, apache, tomcat, xampp

What's wrong here? Why when I click Admin button, localhost cannot be accessed? Please help !!

[image]

When I type `localhost:7777` and select `phpMyAdmin`, I get this

[image]

Comment: Have you tried going to either `localhost:4499` or `localhost:7777` in your browser?

Comment: @J.Titus tried 7777 and it shows dashboard. Is it fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The issue is default ports. you need to browse manually to: `localhost:7777`, cause it's differs from the default localhost port, the GUI takes you.*

As seen in GUI, Your mysql is open at port: `3307`.

The default port for mysql is `3306`.

phpmyadmin is trying to access mysql at the default port (`3306`), and so it fails.

Solution would be:

**1. ether change your mysql to listen on port `3306`.**

**2. or, change phpmyadmin to access mysql at your current port, 3307.**

How to do that?

1. As you see in the debug prints in your GUI, your not running XAMPP as admin.
   maybe if you run it as admin, it'll listen at port 3306.
   if that doesn't help, than:
2. open your phpmyadmin config file (path: xampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php),
   and add this line:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']='3307 ';`

after:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`.

now, your phpmyadmin will access mysql on the right port.

*P.S.*

*Your ports are different than default, cause ether someone changed it manually in your config files, or that a different process is using them*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98932/discussion-between-john-joe-and-captain-crunch).